# How to use UI virtualization with redefined ListBox templates

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, virtualization, ui-virtualization

I'm trying to use ListBox as a view containing multiple items and, of course, I need to use UI virtualization in it.

The problem is virtualization works only when I declare ListBox this way:

```
<ListBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}" 
    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
    VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <views:SiteEntryView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

But if I try to customize it, it doesn't virtualizing anymore:

```
<ListBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}" 
    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
    VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">

    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>

    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <views:SiteEntryView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

As far as I've found, this sample contains just the same that ListBox contains by default. But virtualization isn't working. I've read several articles and also couple of answers here, but still can't figure out the "general way" - what and where I must set, bind, add, etc to make virtualization work with custom templates?

Comment: Should I use `<ScrollViewer />` on top of `<ListBox />` to create the scroller with virtualization ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you're using a `StackPanel` for your `ItemsPanel` - you should be using a `VirtualizingStackPanel` instead (which is also the default ItemsPanel for ListBox).

Either remove your `ItemsPanel` definition or modify it to use a `VirtualizingStackPanel`:

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: I definitely tried both, but now I tried it again and it works. :\ I wonder what was wrong before.

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

Update your `PanelTemplate` to use a `VirtualizingStackPanel` and add your `virtualization` options to the `ScrollViewer` of the `ControlTemplate`.

```
<ListBox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <ScrollViewer VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                      VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
            <ItemsPresenter />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ListBox.Template>

<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <VirtualizingStackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>

<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <views:SiteEntryView />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I see that properties works either on ListBox or ScrollViewer. Does It mean that properties can be set on some root of a visual tree (I mean some element that appears root to its child tree), or is it some WPF's "automagical" stuff?

Comment: I've experienced issues in the past (with lots of real-time data) that the properties did not work well when provided on the root ListBox node. I forgot where, but I came across a blog post that stated it should be set within the ControlTemplate itself; and ever since then virutalizaiton has been working better.

Comment: @d.moncada You're right! It seems that List View doesn't have this problem?